# Laravel - Model boot creating not firing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like `$protected $foo` to be assigned `'foo'` in the `static::creating` event, but when I output the final object, the property is null. The event does not seem to fire:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model {

    protected $foo;

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function (Item $item) {
            echo "successfully fired";   //this does not get echoed
            $item->foo = 'foo';
        });
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15):

Your code is working fine, I tested at my end in this way

**In Model**

```
protected $foo;

public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    //while creating/inserting item into db  
    static::creating(function (AccountCreation $item) {
        echo "successfully fired";   
        $item->foo = 'fooasdfasdfad'; //assigning value
    });

    //once created/inserted successfully this method fired, so I tested foo 
    static::created(function (AccountCreation $item) {
        echo "<br /> {$item->foo} ===== <br /> successfully fired created";   
    });
}
```

**in Controller**

```
AccountCreation::create(['by'=>'as','to'=>'fff','hash'=>'aasss']);
```

**in browser, got this response**

```
successfully fired
fooasdfasdfad =====
successfully fired created
```

Comment: while inserting, behind the scene creating/created events are triggered...

Comment: no.....ok, that's true, `create()` will trigger `creating/created` events.... but `insert()` will not trigger the events....so, that's why i ask "is there any event that will triggered for `insert()` ??

Comment: you can also try saving() and saved() events

Comment: you can pass multi-dimensional array in insert method.
`insert([
['name'=>'name 1','class'=>'1st'],
['name'=>'name 2','class'=>'2nd'],
['name'=>'name 3','class'=>'3rd']
])`

Comment: I think you are correct, creating/created is not being triggered when using insert. I switched to create for now...

Comment: How to get old data for `updating`?

Answer (score 3):

I used this code in laravel 9:

```
    protected static function booted()
{
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->code = self::generateUniqueCode();
    });
}
```